# Java - Recycleview viewholder.category_name.settext is not working

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

```
@Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder viewHolder, Category model, int i) {
                viewHolder.category_name.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso.with(getActivity())
                        .load(model.getImage())
                        .into(viewHolder.category_image);

                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
//                        FancyToast.makeText(getActivity(),String.format("%d|%s",adapter.getRef(position).getKey(),model.getName()),FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG,FancyToast.SUCCESS,true).show();
                        Intent startGame = new Intent(getActivity(),Start.class);
                        Common.categoryId = adapter.getRef(position).getKey();
                        startActivity(startGame);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

I have Tried the below code but viewHolder.category_name.setText() is not working 
Actually setText is working but model.getName() is not working

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: No error but the string that im trying to retrieve from firebase database is returning an empty string

Comment: `not working` how exactly?

Comment: its returning an empty string but the database is loaded with name  -

Comment: here is the link to database structure https://ibb.co/ZLzYhxv

Comment: it looks like your category contains multiple-element try to debug  populateViewHolder() and check the value of Category object

Comment: how to do that @GaneshGudghe

Comment: `setText()` does not return anything. it can't return empty string

Comment: what do you mean @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: you wrote `but viewHolder.category_name.setText() is not working`. I asked `how exactly?`. You wrote `its returning an empty string`. I wrote `setText() does not return anything. it can't return empty string`

Comment: when i tried setText("ABCD")...it worked ...but when i tried setText(model.getName()); it didnt work